# Thingsboard cluster setup

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing, apache-zookeeper, thingsboard

[Building a Thingsboard cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ku9Bt.jpg)
I need help setting up a Thingsboard cluster, the documentation online is very limited.
The cluster will contain 2 Zookeeper nodes and 4 Thingsboard nodes with Cassandra DB.
Should Zookeeper be installed separately?
A step-by-step guide would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I cannot provide you detailed step-by-step instructions to setup a ThingsBoard cluster. I can point you into the right direction by sharing the different documents you need to do so.

Bottom line, the following tasks must be completed:

1. Install and configure a ZooKeeper ensemble.

Check the [ZooKeeper documentation](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperStarted.html#sc_RunningReplicatedZooKeeper) for further installation details. Keep in mind that you need at least three different ZK-nodes in a clustered environment and that you always need an odd number of ZK nodes (3,5,7,...). It is a **very very very bad idea** to build a cluster consisting out of two ZK-nodes, check split brain condition that might appear under these circumstances! Basically you setup the number of individual nodes you wish to use and change the configuration file to enable the different nodes as an ensemble. This is documented quite well in the ZK-docs.

2. Install and configure a Cassandra cluster.

Again you will setup the number of individual nodes you need for your Cassandra cluster and modify the individual configuration files to convert them into a Cassandra cluster. Check [Cassandra documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-a-multi-node-cluster-database-with-cassandra-on-ubuntu-14-04) for details. Be sure to check proper configuration using the `nodetool status` command as described at the end of the document. All your nodes should be up and running.

3. Install and configure a ThingsBoard cluster.

Use the instructions provided with [ThingsBoard single node setup](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/linux/).

- Install Java
- Skip External database installation
- ThingsBoard service installation
- Configure ThingsBoard to use the external database - Cassandra
- Go to [Cluster setup](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/cluster-setup/) and apply the configuration steps depicted (ZK, Cassandra and RPC). Keep in mind to point to ALL members of your ZK, Cassandra cluster. You can also use IP-addresses instead of host names.
- Return to single node setup and run the installation script at ONE NODE only!
- Start ThingsBoard service

If everything went well, you should be able to access your ThingsBoard nodes directly using the URL http://[NODE_IP]:8080. You can verify proper cluster operation by creating a tenant on one node and check its presence on another node.

I don't know if using an even number of ThingsBoard nodes is a good idea. The documentation does not mention anything about this.

One final remark, you could/should consider putting a proxy in front of your ThingsBoard cluster to provide load balancing to your web clients and improve user experience. This way you shouldn't share the individual host addresses with your users and you will prevent node overloading due to the fact that everybody is using the same web-address to access your dashboard(s). You could also proxy your MQTT broker to provide load balancing as well.

Good luck in setting up your cluster!

Answer (score 0):

Zookeeper needs at least 3 nodes to run in a cluster mode. Each node voting and the valid replica count to gain the QUORUM is 3.